# Who are the Four Generals based on?

Tags: the-devil-is-a-part-timer

In the anime, there are four generals: Lucifer, Alciel, Malacoda, and Adramelech, and they all work under the devil. I'm wondering which group of 4 these demons are based on.

I've mostly thought that the 4 princes: Satan, Lucifer, Belial, and Leviathan can be counted out because Satan is included in, but I'm not 100% sure.

There are also the four horsemen of the apocalypse: Pestilence, Death, Famine, and War.

There are also the 4 demons at the Euphrates, but I don't know too much about them.

I'm not sure about any other groups, but I'm sure they must be based on something, the anime was great with tying in the Christian faith into the mix, so I can only assume that they'd include the four generals as some sort of a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucifer is based on the fallen angel Lucifer, who was banished from heaven for revolting against God. (At least in the Hebrew and Christian mythology, but he also appears in [other mythologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer).

Arsiel is another name for [Azazel](https://books.google.hu/books?id=NCBVAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=Arsiel&source=bl&ots=NIWay0wWcd&sig=D46fazffcxA1AC1YYbNdTsgUFuM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjk-oum853WAhWIL1AKHWfJCrEQ6AEIZzAP#v=onepage&q=Arsiel&f=false), at least according to the satanist bible, The Bible of the Adversary.

Malacoda is based on the [character of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malacoda) who appears in Dante's Inferno.

Adramelech is a [deity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adramelech) mentioned in the Hebrew bible and is considered a demon, like many other pagan deities.

Seeing how the four of them have almost nothing to do with each other it is likely that the author just picked some random demon names from the western culture.